# Folder has gone missing from AppData, why?

Tags: windows, windows-8, appdata

I have an old SSD with a Windows 8.1 installation on it. I am trying to track down a cryptocoin wallet that I had been using back in 2014 and is typically stored in AppData\Roaming. The thing is, the folder it was in has disappeared. The software that put the folder there (dated as installed in 2014 in Explorer) is still installed under Program Files (x86), and I can see by the last modified dates on files that the disk is relatively untouched since that time, including the AppData folder. So, why would the folder in looking for specifically be missing and everything else pretty much intact? I didn’t uninstall the software. Is there anyway I could find out what happened or to recover it?

Comment: AppData has some Virtual File System projection characteristics, so when logged in, the AppData directory may contain directories projected in from other locations, like the Default Users appdata, etc. Check all the user profiles, and be sure to check local and locallow as well.

Comment: Search the entire drive for the bitcoin file, not the folder.